# AZURE VM Disabling Windows Update Service

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Two Azure B1ms VMs with Premium SSD storage have been running great for 3 years.  Light use, only run IIS and two PowerShell scripts, CPU and memory has been less than 50% most of the time.

Recently, they both started to run really slowly, exhibited by scripts running 5 minutes late, failed file writes and RDP failing to connect.  Managed to logon and run Task Manager, which took 2-3 minutes to load, and discovered the CPU is sitting continuously on 99-100%

I've disabled **Windows Update, Background Intelligent Transfer** and rebooted.

Apart from brief jumps to 90% CPU caused by some Background processes, CPU now sits at 1% most of the time.

What is the downside and/or exposure of switching off the Windows Update Service..?

Note: I could run Windows Update from the UI, while Defender continues to get new definitions.

[image: MASSIVE DROP IN CPU USAGE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Very Low in CPU utilization after disabled Windows Update, Background Intelligent Transfer and rebooted is expected.

B-Series is general purpose VM is used for many workloads that run in Azure, like web servers, small databases, and development and test environments, the CPU performance is very bursty. **These workloads will run for a long time using a small fraction of the CPU performance possible and then spike to needing the full power of the CPU due to incoming traffic or required work**

So, the B1ms VM is utilizing 90% of the CPU when you were running script and some background processes like window update. But once you rebooted, disable the window update and stops all background process then CPU uses is very less.

This using only a fraction of the CPU when you don’t need it and burst up to 100% of the CPU when you do need it.

You can refer this Microsoft Document: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/introducing-b-series-our-new-burstable-vm-size/

Comment: Thanks, read that, although still don't understand why Windows Update consumes so much CPU to the point of crippling other applications. My question was: Does it matter if Windows Update service is disabled..?

Comment: Yes it does matter , Because B1ms VM is use for light use only if you updating the window it does update your overall OS system including security patches and feature as well so that might be possibilities to consume more CPU.

Comment: Yeah sure, but who cares..? The VM is useless if the only application it is capable of running is it's own update service and nothing else.